# How to detect laravel logout time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

someone knows how to record the user's logout time in the database. Laravel. I made the entry time, I don’t understand how to pick up the exit time.

Comment: Do you mean when a user explicitly has logged out (by e.g. clicking a logout button) or do you also want to catch when a user "logged out" when a user's session expired?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen `Logout` event and update field.

First - create a Listener:

```
php artisan make:listener UpdateLogoutTime
```

Than, register it in `EventServiceProvider`

```
use App\Listeners\UpdateLogoutTime;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Logout::class => [
            UpdateLogoutTime::class
        ]
    ];
}
```

Than, make update logic in listener:

```
class UpdateLogoutTime
{
    public function handle(Logout $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        //update time logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Auth::user()->update([ 'logout_time' => now() ]);
Auth::logout();
```

Or,

```
$id = Auth::id();

if(Auth::logout()) {
    User::where('id', $id)->update([ 'logout_time' => now() ]);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to write like this in middleware if(Auth::logout()){Auth::user()->update([ 'logout_time' => now() ]);}

Comment: I updated my answer, also you can do like that.

Comment: looks perfect, will check and write, thanks